# How was Ernest Littlefield able to survive for 50 years?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In Season 1 Episode 11, *Heliopolis*, SG-1 travels to a planet where we first learn of the alliance for 4 races, and discover that Ernest Littlefield had survived his trip through the gate in 1945, and had been living alone until they arrived, some 50+ years later. The [wiki page](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Heliopolis) for Heliopolis states that the planet's life had been completely extinguished, and Ernest was the first, and only, living thing on the planet. So, how did one man, who had no supplies, manage to live for 50 years? Should he not have died of starvation after only a month or two after arriving?

Comment: What's more, SG-1 arrives just as the place he's been living for decades is about to be destroyed.

Comment: @Buzz - I'm pretty sure the vibrations from the stargate were responsible for the collapse.

Comment: There was also a thunderstorm happening.

Comment: "Should he not have died of starvation after only a month or two after arriving?" I'd be more concerned about dying within a few days due to lack of water.

Comment: @jpmc26 - For all we know, that ocean is fresh water

Comment: @Valorum Seems a bit unlikely since salt in the ocean is a result of erosion

Comment: @DKNguyen - Sure, but if the world had very little salt in the bedrock (or something sort of microorganism was gobbling up the salt) then the ocean could be drinkable fresh water.

Comment: @Valorum When I say "salt: what I mean is dissolved minerals rather than strictly NaCl. A lot of dissolved minerals taste salty in high concentrations I think.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The long-shot of the castle shows that it's directly adjacent to an ocean. The land in the distance appears to have green on it. Since we know that he didn't take food supplies, **it seems highly likely that Ernest subsisted on fish, whatever wildlife he could trap and whatever plants/greenery he could find**, noting that when he first talks to Daniel he hands him a [piece of fruit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKxQG.png) <sub><sup>(h/t to @KeralynBrooks for spotting that)</sup></sub>.

[image]

---

For the record, the wiki source that claims that the planet is entirely devoid of life is from a mission pack in the [(canon)](https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/49104-stargate-atlantis-novels/page10?p=12463850#post12463850) role-playing game [Stargate: Fantastic Frontiers](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1:_Fantastic_Frontiers:_Stargate_Season_One), and as such can be dismissed entirely since it conflicts with what we see on screen.

Comment: You gotta love misleading, non-canon information being added to wiki's without clear distinction as to which is which. I haven't gotten a chance to read any of the books yet, so assumed it had come from one of those. Thanks.

Comment: @Daishozen - The books are non-canon as well, even the novelisations.

Comment: So, basically, if it isn't in the show it didn't happen?

Comment: @Daishozen - Your mileage may vary. As far as canon is concerned, it goes on-screen, then everything else including the novelisations, interviews, EU novels, RPG games, etc etc

Comment: @Daishozen It didn’t happen regardless. It is fiction, you decide what you accept as part of the story.

Comment: @11684 It's not unreasonable to ask for internally consistent fiction, though. Suspension of disbelief only goes so far.

Comment: @Daishozen - I don't think there are any explicitly canon SG1 novels, etc at all but there *are* some SGA and SGU post series comics that are cannon. There are also a few SGA post series novels that are purportedly canon even though they conflict with those canon comics. I'm not sure if any SGA or novels set *during* the series run are canon or not.  It is what it is, which isn't all that clear.

Comment: @JohnA - Allegedly, the fandemonium books and Stargate RPGs are fully canon; https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/49104-stargate-atlantis-novels/page10?p=12463850#post12463850 - That all being said, the studio fully reserves the right to ignore the events therein

Comment: @Valorum - I'm not sure it would add much to the answer but it's entirely possible Littlefield had been a boy scout with plenty of basic Bushcraft and could identify plants (mostly from Earth) that were safe to eat.

Comment: @JohnA - Being a boyscout on a strange world wouldn't have much impact on what you eat. I'm guessing it's a case of trial and error. Very few earth plants will actually kill you *if you start with a relatively small amount*.

Comment: @Valorum - but that's the thing, or more accurately two things. SG1 and SGA both make it clear that not only do planets have what look like trees they *are* trees as well as other species of plants from Earth that make the botanists of the Atlantis expedition all kiddy to find in Pegasus. A scout would recognize plants and would've been specifically taught how to test what wasn't recognized. And being a scout back then was like playing video games today. Very common.

Answer (score 25):

He was seen holding a purple ball of something (fruit?), and he said

> 'Eat'

so probably he survived mainly on plant life.

[image]

Comment: Good find. I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot of what appears to be a piece of fruit.

Comment: Looking at the closeup version, it looks like a bell pepper that's either purple or dark brown. Not sure if you can find those for sale or it was painted.

Comment: @CTeegarden I wonder if the fruit could have been easily chromakeyed, since bell peppers are naturally green!

Comment: @PhasedOut Spray paint is a thing, you know. There are ways to change colours outside of a computer!

Comment: purple peppers are a thing. easier than spray paint @Graham http://www.territorialseed.com/product/Purple-Star-Pepper-Seed/purple_power

Comment: @JCRM Cool, I'll have to find some of those for this summer. :)

Comment: Definitely not a guango!

Answer (score 0):

When they say the planet was devoid of life, I'm sure they specifically meant sentient life. The planet was unoccupied by civilization, therefore it was a neutral meeting ground for multiple civilizations.

The episode clearly shows evidence of plant life, which means the planet definitely supports life, and there were things he could eat. How he managed to not eat something poisonous or toxic in 50 years on an alien planet is remarkable.